# Jquery menu - alter sliding functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with this menu, when I hover to the subcategories they keep slideup.

I want the subcategories to remain when I hover it and when I move my mouse outside it will slideup, same go to the main categories. Please help. I had been working on this for 1 hour but no solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('ul#level1').slideUp();
       $('a#tab').hover(function(){
                 var content_show = $(this).attr('title');
                $('.'+ content_show).stop().slideDown();

            },function(){


                var content_show = $(this).attr('title');
                $('.'+ content_show).stop().slideUp();


            });
 });





                <li><a href="#" id="tab" class="active" title="one">Sport</a>

                    <ul id="level1" class="one">
                    <li><a href="#">View All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >T-Shirt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >Hats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pants</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </li>

                <li><a href="#" id="tab" class="tab" title="two">Foods</a>

                    <ul id="level1" class="two">
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to slide your `<li>` not your `<a>` **DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/VNkbp/

Actually I agree with @PraveenKumar but if you are still want to use jquery I recommend you to use `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems to be okay. Check out this code, using pure CSS, as this would help you to port it to JavaScript. You don't need to use `title`:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)